# Looking for a cheap small arduino ish board

Tags: bluetooth, project

I'm looking for a cheap and small bluetooth board for a project.
I found [this](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-1259.html) one, but I find this one too expensive, are there cheaper alternatives, in similar size?

Thank you!

Comment: An ESP32 module?

Comment: preferably an all in one, for the project I currently use a wemos d1 mini, which works fine, but wifi isn't the best way of controlling it. that's why I'm looking into bluetooth

Comment: And that's why I suggested ESP32.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was confused by something else, this was indeed what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: I guessed you'd confused it with the ESP8266, which is WiFi only. The ESP32 is WiFi and BLE combined in one chip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest investigating the ESP32.

It's not only a far more powerful chip than any normal Arduino, but it has both WiFI *and* Bluetooth Low Energy, all on the one chip.

It's available as surface mount modules, similar to the ESP8266, and there are a number of small development boards that have been created around it as well.